# Grails Base64 to PDF - render a PDF inline

Tags: grails, pdf, groovy

I have a Grails controller action that calls a service that will return XML that contains a base64 representation of a PDF. Here is an (abbreviated) example sample.

```
<response status="Success"><messages/><values><pages>8</pages></values><xml/><files><pdf name="FitnessApplication" content-type="application/pdf"><![CDATA[JVBERi0xLjQKJeL ... </files></response>
```

After we parse that out I want to display that PDF in the browser. So far I am able to decode the string and render it using the file attribute of the render method. This serves up the PDF correctly as a download but I want it to display in the browser (inline) and NOT as a file download.

```
Map responseMap = new XmlParserHelper().parse( formsResponse.payload )
byte[] decoded = responseMap.files.pdf.decodeBase64()
render( file: decoded, fileName: "${document}.pdf", contentType: "application/pdf",  )
```

I tried setting the content disposition as both an option to render and in the header map but neither seem to do the trick. Does anyone know how I can serve this PDF to the user in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send it in the response.  But you need to add the headers on your own.  E.g. something like:

```
response.contentType = "application/pdf"
response.contentLength = FileUtils.copyFile(pdfFile, response.outputStream)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help cfrick, that worked out great. I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

To build on what **cfrick** said here is the final solution I went with.

```
// response data
byte[] pdfData = responseMap.files.pdf.decodeBase64()
response.contentType = "application/pdf"
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename='dan.pdf'")

// write to output 
OutputStream output = response.outputStream
output.write(pdfData);
output.close();
```